# How to remove characters in columns in R?

Tags: r, database

This is the data frame I have, but I only want the numbers from the frame. How can I remove `~th pick`/all characters ?

```
[1] " 1st pick "   " 2nd pick "   " 4th pick "   " 5th pick "   " 6th pick "   " 7th pick "  
[7] " 8th pick "   " 9th pick "   " 10th pick "  " 11th pick "  " 12th pick "  " 13th pick " 
[13] " 14th pick "  " 15th pick "  " 16th pick "  " 17th pick "  " 18th pick "  " 19th pick " 
[19] " 20th pick "  " 21st pick "  " 22nd pick "  " 23rd pick "  " 24th pick "  " 25th pick " 
[25] " 26th pick "  " 27th pick "  " 28th pick "  " 29th pick "  " 30th pick "  " 31st pick " 
[31] " 32nd pick "  " 33rd pick "  " 34th pick "  " 35th pick "  " 36th pick "  " 37th pick " 
[37] " 38th pick "  " 39th pick "  " 40th pick "  " 41st pick "  " 42nd pick "  " 43rd pick " 
[43] " 44th pick "  " 45th pick "  " 46th pick "  " 47th pick "  " 48th pick "  " 49th pick " 
[49] " 50th pick "  " 51st pick "  " 52nd pick "  " 53rd pick "  " 54th pick "  " 55th pick " 
[55] " 56th pick "
```

Comment: Look at `?sub`, a simple google search should show you how to get it done.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a data frame `df` with a single column `col` containing this data, you can use `gsub()` to extract the number you want:

```
df$number <- gsub(".*(\\d+)+.*", "\\1", df$col)
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(col=c(" 1st pick ", " 2nd pick ", " 4th pick ", " 5th pick ",
                       " 6th pick ", " 7th pick "))
```

**Due to peer pressure:**

You could also just use:

```
df$number <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", df$col)
```

Comment: Or just `gsub("[^0-9]","",x)`

Answer (score 3):

Using the data above from @Ronak and `stringr` package, you can do something like this:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c(" 1st pick ", " 2nd pick " ," 4th pick " ," 5th pick ", " 6th pick " ,
       " 7th pick ", " 8th pick ", " 9th pick " ," 10th pick " ," 11th pick ",
       " 12th pick " ," 13th pick " )
as.numeric(str_extract_all(x, '\\d+'))
```

Output is as follows:

```
[1]  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option with `gsub`

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", x))
#[1]  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

#### data

```
x <- c(" 1st pick ", " 2nd pick " ," 4th pick " ," 5th pick ", " 6th pick " ,
   " 7th pick ", " 8th pick ", " 9th pick " ," 10th pick " ," 11th pick ",
   " 12th pick " ," 13th pick " )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all the numbers by using

```
unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", x)))

#[1] "1"  "2"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13"
```

As per comments by the @thelatemail, you could avoid using `unlist` by

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("\\d+",x))
```

---

Alternatively, if you have a vector only with numbers and characters, you can get rid of all the characters as well with,

```
as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", x))

#[1]  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

**data**

```
x <- c(" 1st pick ", " 2nd pick " ," 4th pick " ," 5th pick ", " 6th pick " ," 7th pick ",
   " 8th pick ", " 9th pick " ," 10th pick " ," 11th pick " ," 12th pick " ," 13th pick " )
```

Comment: You could do away with the `unlist` in the first example - `regmatches(x, regexpr("\\d+",x))` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
x<-c(" 1st pick "," 2nd pick "," 4th pick "," 5th pick "," 6th pick "," 45th pick "," 46th pick "," 47th pick "," 48th pick ")

a <- function(x)as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,"st pick|nd pick|th pick")))
x <- a(x)
x <- x[!is.na(x)]
[1]  1  2  4  5  6 45 46 47 48
```

or you can use without  defining a function

```
x <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,"st pick|nd pick|th pick")))
x <- x[!is.na(x)]
[1]  1  2  4  5  6 45 46 47 48
```